# Which Drools product to use for timetabling?

Tags: jsp, drools, timetable, drools-planner

*Yes, it's a newb question.*

I want to make a timetabling application that these points specific to my situation:

1. At a single time, we are allocating a maximum of
   (3 teachers X 6 hours)X(3 classes X 35 hour workweek) at a single go, we are **iteratively** building the timetable.
2. There will be impossible states and any impossible timetables must be notified without the application getting stuck- we expect this application to be pushed to it's limits.
3. It must return results in a **constant** time or report that it failed.

---

I intend to run it as a **JSP application** on Tomcat 6. The execution is as:

1. A PHP application **"POSTs in"** the entire data and rule set
2. wait till it finishes executing
3. read the response containing the optimized state

The JSP stuff is just for **convenience**, as it seems the easiest way to transfer and keep alive the program.

Correct me if this is an unmanageable situation.

---

Which of the Drools products makes it possible? Or is there a simpler configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) does. It even has a lesson scheduling example called **curriculum course**. Just start by copy pasting that example.

1) is not a problem, the example uses far bigger datasets.
2) Because timetabling is NP-complete proving 2) for any case in reasonable time is impossible. Lowerbound calculations are not yet supported, but could be partially helpful in some cases.
3) is not a problem. You configure how much time you want it to give. (or stop it asynchronously from another thread just before you need a solution).

The Tomcat with JSP approach should pose no problem.